# opswork chef 11.10, custom json attributes timeout of unicorn

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

do you do how the syntax config is? I find a lot opswork 's document but still not see it concern that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the Nginx [recipe](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/nginx/attributes/nginx.rb#L67) attributes. Unicorn [recipe](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/unicorn/attributes/default.rb) attributes don't have what you're looking for.

`{"nginx":{"proxy_read_timeout":"900", "proxy_send_timeout":"500"}}`

Comment: ok let try it.  And :  is there any option can apply changed enviroments and json attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on what cookbooks you are using which you didn't mention. Additionally 11.x is no longer supported and is likely unsafe to use.

Comment: thanks for reply. Because I stuck with the version of Amazon 2014.09.  not available update . So just keep suffering with that